# Hive: When insert into partitioned table, in most of the rows, hive double url-encode the partition key column

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-partitioning

I created a partitioned table:

```
create table  t1 ( amount double) partitioned by ( events_partition_key string) stored as paquet;
```

added some data to tmp_table, where column 'events_partition_key' contains timestamp (string type) in the following format: "2018-02-25 00:00:00"

Then I insert some data into the partitioned table.

```
insert into table t1 partition (events_partition_key)
select amount, events_partition_key
from tmp_table
```

when selecting from the new partitioned table t1, in some cases events_partition_key column is presented regularly the same it appeared in tmp_table  i.e.  "2018-02-25 00:00:00", but in most cases, it appears URL-encoded, i.e. "2018-02-25 00%3A00%3A00"

[image: this is how it looks like when selecting distinct events_partition_key]

In any case, the original column partition_key has no difference in cases where it was URL-encoded or not,

when showing partitions for the new table:

```
show partitions t1;
```

I got everything URL-encoded twice (i.e. "2018-02-25 00%253A00%253A00"), but some cases it was only once (i.e. "2018-02-25 00%3A00%3A00")

[image]

there is nothing wrong in the original values, only after it has become a partition key.

Comment: I also tried it with 'textfile' instead of 'parquet' and had the same problem. tried it with a small dataset, it worked fine, even with partition keys that previously had double encoding

Comment: tested on hive version: hive-1.1.0-cdh5.9.1

Answer (score 1):

If possible partition by date instead of timestamp.

If not possible:

This Jira [**HIVE-3679**](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3679) adds **hive.decode.partition.name** property to the HiveConf.java in release 0.10.0

Try to set it true.

```
set hive.decode.partition.name=true;
```